# In Python, is there a way of saying "if x == 2 or x == 3" without repeating the "x==" part twice?

Tags: python, if-statement

Take for example this code:

```
if int(str(x)[len(str(x)) - 1]) == 0 or int(str(x)[len(str(x)) - 1]) == 5:
   return False
```

Supposing I have even a bigger list of `or`'s, is there an easier way of doing this?

Ok, now that I know to use if `x in ( , , , etc)`, how do I implement this into this:

`filter(lambda x: int(str(x)[len(str(x)) - 1]) in (0, 5), range(1000))` Got it, wrong parenthesis, bad python programmer.

Comment: How is that obviously wrong? Besides the mismatched parentheses.

Comment: Why aren't you using `x % 10` instead of this string thing? You'll need to get used to doing math with math operations instead of text manipulation at some point.

Comment: For your specific case `if x % 2 == 1:` will work.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is like this:

```
if x in (2,3):
    ....
```

If you have a large number of candidate values, then this will result in a linear search which could be expensive. If that matters then a set could result in better performance:

```
if x in set((2,3)):
    ....
```

Note that any performance benefit from using a set could only come if the set could be instantiated once, but tested for membership multiple times.

```
myset = set((2,3))
....
if x in myset:
    ....
```

---

It looks to me that you are actually testing divisibility by 5 which can be done like this:

```
if x % 5 == 0:
    ....
```

Comment: because the question is too simple, you should add something about using sets for big lists, as OP suggests he might have

Comment: Downvoting because the set version constructs a tuple, then turns it into a set, every single time.

Comment: @user2357112 You could only gain a benefit if you could instantiate the set once, but test membership multiple times. I added a note to that effect.

Comment: In Python3, you should use literal sets `x in {2, 3}` etc. as there is an optimisation that converts them to frozen sets when the function is defined, so there is extra construction overhead.

Comment: There is trade-off between between using `set` and `tuple`: `set` has faster look up time(constant time vs. linear time), but `set` takes up more memory.

Comment: frozenset can be even faster

Answer (score 1):

Use the ´in´ operator:

```
if x in (2, 3):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
if int(str(x)[-1])  in (0,5):
   return False
```

Note that `some_array[-1]` returns the last element in `some_array` so that you don't have to do `some_array[len(sum_array) - 1]`

Comment: That's the last element of a string. I also know I can use [-1:] to do that, but thanks for the help.